# JS how right replace `&quot` on quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="Autocomlete1" name="test">

$('.Autocomlete1').typeahead({
            ajax: {
                    url: './test.php?log=test',
                    triggerLength: 1
                  },
            updater: function(item) {
                    return item;
                },
            onSelect: function(item) {

                    return item;
                }
    });
```

After autocomplate in `input` we get nextvalue -  `Text &quot; TextTextText &quot;` (database row have it value) but need output `Text " TextTextText "`

For replace `&quot;` on `"` i want make:

```
onSelect: function(item) {
  var text = item.text;
  var text = text.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
  $('.Autocomlete1').val(text);
  return item;
}
```

But this is not working...

Tell me please how right replace `&quot` on quotes ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

if not working `var text = text.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');` check other lines becouse it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me:
var text = text.replace(/&quot;/g, '\"');

Comment: how about the rest of the escapes? this is not a roadworthy answer (or question)

Answer (score 7):

" is also needs a escape character before in string write '\"

```
 var text = text.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
```

Comment: This works for me except only in this format: `.replace(/&quot;/g, '\"')`