# Removing \&quote; from the beginning of an url

Tags: javascript

I want to remove "&quote; from the beginning of an url like for instance when a url has something like this href="&quot;https://www.google.com" how do i get rid of the &quote; from the beginning of the url using javascript.

I tried something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('a[href^="\&quot;https://"]').each(function(){ 
        var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
      
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("\&quot;https://", "https://"); // Create new url
        $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
    });
});

<a href="\&quot;https://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="\&quot;https://www.gmail.com">Gmail</a>
```

The working code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").each(function() { 
        //console.log($(this).attr("href")); 
        var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace('\\"', ' ');
        //console.log($(this).attr("href").replace('\\"', ' '));
        $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
    });
    });
```

Comment: This other post seems to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443682/js-how-right-replace-quot-on-quotes Tell me if it works for you. If not, we can investigate further :)

Comment: If may be using them will be possible, since this is not working, so if someone can give ideas to solve this using mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Comment: `wordpress` and `vue.js` don't make sense either...

Comment: I got this problem from wordpress while using vue.js so have tagged them if this is a regular problem while using vue.js

Comment: _"This doesnt remove the &quot;"_ -> `$("a").each(function() { console.log($(this).attr("href")); });`

Comment: This looks like XY problem Why is there quot; in the first place? It should preferably be removed where it originally occurs

Comment: somehow vue.js is appending \" to urls now this is happening externally from another source, which means the file is not on my end so want to fix it with replace for the time being while the people on the other end removes the \" on their end.

Comment: solved. Thanks @Andreas for showing the way...

was using wrong slashes for \
needed this: replace('\\"', ' ');

since single \ makes a coder life living hell...

Comment: The problem isn't widely known and not specific to Vue. Vue itself doesn't have such problems. This means that either urls or  HTML markup is bad. You're trying to patch a bigger problem locally.